# How to track an error generated by providing wrong instrumentation key in Azure App Insights

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, analytics, azure-application-insights, apm

I'm using Azure app Insights for collecting analytical data.I want to handle a case where I'm getting a 400 error due to providing the wrong instrumentation key in the AppInsights.js file. I have created a profile for encrypting instrumentation key in App. Where can I catch this error in code and display fallback UI in a React App.The backend is in Java.

[image: Errors]

```
import { ApplicationInsights from'@microsoft/applicationinsightsweb';
import {ReactPlugin,AppInsightsErrorBoundary,} from 
'@microsoft/applicationinsights-react-js';
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';
import { ClickAnalyticsPlugin } from '@microsoft/applicationinsights- 
clickanalytics-js';

import io from 'react/IOGlobal';
const clickPluginInstance = new ClickAnalyticsPlugin();

const browserHistory = createBrowserHistory({ basename: '' });
const reactPlugin = new ReactPlugin();
const clickPluginConfig = {
  autoCapture: true,
  dataTags: {
    useDefaultContentNameOrId: true,
  },
};
const appInsights = new ApplicationInsights({
  config: { instrumentationKey: 
***io.platform.getProfileValue('APP_INSTRUMENTATION_KEY')***,
extensions: [reactPlugin, clickPluginInstance],
extensionConfig: {
  [reactPlugin.identifier]: { history: browserHistory },
  [clickPluginInstance.identifier]: clickPluginConfig,
    },
  },
});

appInsights.loadAppInsights();
export default { reactPlugin, appInsights };
```

Also please help with any other implementation in App Insights to catch the same error.
Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. In its current form, this question is not a great fit for SO. It is not clear what you actually want to achieve and where you failed. Please refer to [ask]. On-topic: are you trying to show something like a message-box when the `track` requests error out because of misconfiguration?

Comment: you are right @rickvdboch. I want to show an error message when a track request gets failed. I have created a profile for encrypting instrumentation key in App , But when we provide the wrong value for the same, an error message should be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Update **index.js** by putting the following route at the end of the route declaration, before `app.listen()`:

```
…

// this matches all routes and all methods

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.status(404).send({
    status: 404,
    error: ‘Not found’
    // You can add your alert
})
})
```

Check here for more info [here](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-handle-errors-in-an-express-and-node-js-app-cb4fe2907ed9)

First need to set the Instrumentation key `.setup(“Instrumentation key”)` To get the instance of the default client that is configured with `.setup("Instrumentation key")` use `appInsights.client`. Alternatively, if you want a new client just use `getClient("Instrumentation key")`.

Just like for setup, you can skip providing the Instrumentation key in code if it's in the special instrumentation key environment variable.

Refer for similar kind of issue [here](https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-node.js/issues/290)